# How to move data from one field one row up or down in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to move Row 2's data into Row 1 how would I do that using SQL Server

| ID | Data1 | DATA3 | DATA4 | DATA6 | DATA7 | DATA8 | DATA9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | DEF | GHIJK |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  | 1,254,800 | 28-Feb-2018 | MWK | 48.00 |
| 3 | LMN | OPQ | RSTUV |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  | 1,558,900 | 28-Feb-2018 | MWK | 49.00 |

I would like my results to display as follows

| ID | Data1 | DATA3 | DATA4 | DATA6 | DATA7 | DATA8 | DATA9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | DEF | GHIJK | 1,254,800 | 28-Feb-2018 | MWK | 48.00 |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | LMN | OPQ | RSTUV | 1,558,900 | 28-Feb-2018 | MWK | 49.00 |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Please provide an example of what results you expect...

Comment: please provide more sample data and the expected result. Unless your table really only contains 2 rows

Comment: Search for LEAD and LAG

Comment: @Squirrel Please see update

Comment: Is it always move row `n + 1`  to row `n`  ?

Comment: @Squirrel Yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Self-join of a CTE on a row_number could work.

```
WITH CTE_DATA AS (
  SELECT *
  , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) 
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
  c1.Data1, c1.Data3, c1.Data4
, c2.Data6, c2.Data7, c2.Data8, c2.Data9 
FROM CTE_DATA c1
LEFT JOIN CTE_DATA c2 
  ON c2.rn = c1.rn + 1;
```

To update the table

```
WITH CTE_DATA AS (
  SELECT *
  , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) 
  FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE c1
SET Data6 = c2.Data6
  , Data7 = c2.Data7
  , Data8 = c2.Data8
  , Data9 = c2.Data9
FROM CTE_DATA c1
LEFT JOIN CTE_DATA c2
  ON c2.rn = c1.rn + 1;
```

Comment: This WORKS!! thank you so much, but how would I use it in an update?

Comment: See update on update.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY` query, group it by `(ID - 1) / 2`

```
SELECT ID, 
       Data1 = MAX(Data1),
       Data2 = MAX(Data2),
       . . . 
       Data9 = MAX(Data9)
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY (ID - 1) / 2
```